# Getting error while parent-child updating data in entity framework using linq

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I'm having two table Client(ClientID,ClientName) and TIN(ClientTinID,Name,ClientID(foreign key)).One client can have multiple entries in TIN table.

I'm using EF database first approach for data access.Insert data working properly but getting following error while editing the data:

```
A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.
```

I'm using following approach to update data:

```
db.Entry(cl).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Do I have to update all ClientID column in TIN table by foreach loop?

What should I do now?

**Fetching data**

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Client client = new Client();
            client.TINs.Add(new TIN { TIN1 = "" });
            return View(client);
        }
```

**POST Data**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Client cl)
        {
            db.Entry(cl).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View(cl);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show how you fetch the data and how you modify it. This can't be answered without it.

Comment: please see my post again

Comment: You create a new Client so you have to set it to `Added`.